# Does "Je cligne des yeux." also mean "I'm squinting."?

Tags: verbes

Firstly, I already know that ***Je cligne des yeux.*** means ***I'm blinking my eyes.*** [(1)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/blink)

[Gif 1](https://tenor.com/en-GB/view/umm-confused-blinking-okay-white-guy-blinking-gif-7513882)

Secondly, I already know that ***Je plisse les yeux.*** means ***I'm squinting.*** [(2)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/squint/614337)

By "squint", I am not talking about the medical condition. The following Gifs show the definition of squint I am talking about: [Gif 2](https://tenor.com/en-GB/view/skeptical-futurama-fry-hmmm-i-got-my-eyes-on-you-gif-17101711) &
[Gif 3](https://tenor.com/en-GB/view/jake-peralta-squinting-read-trying-to-read-brooklyn-nine-nine-gif-13387080)

[Here is the definition of *plisser*:](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/plisser)

[image]

The following show the definitions of **cligner**.

[Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/cligner)

[image]

[Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C2592)

[image]

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cligner/16527)

[image]

I would like to know, does "Je cligne des yeux." **also** mean "I'm squinting."?

Comment: Le sens premier de squinting est “strabisme" "avoir les yeux qui louchent” : les deux yeux ne focalisent pas sur le même point/focus/centre d'intérêt. Dans un sens symbolique, c'est se focaliser sur deux centres d'intérêts différents, comme dire oui d'un œil et de l'autre, calculer la façon de transformer ce semblant d'accord en refus.

Comment: I've never heard it used that way, but if all dictionaries agree...

Comment: @guillaume31 — https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/squinting%0A

Comment: @Personne sorry, I should have tagged user31453, I was commenting on their question

Comment: @guillaume31 … pas d'inquiétude… j'ai été moi-même surpris de découvrir ce sens !

Comment: @user31453 What are you actually asking? Whether all three dictionaries you’re quoting are wrong? Some clarification is needed as to what you’d accept as a proof for that. Current answers only show that some speakers don’t know that acceptation of _cligner_.

Comment: So… The short answer is “yes”, and you have provided sufficient evidence for that. This question is not useful.

Answer (score -1):

"To squint" translates as indeed *plisser les yeux*, when used in the meaning of "look at someone or something with one or both eyes partly closed in an attempt to see more clearly or as a reaction to strong light".

But note that the other meaning of the English word "to squint" , ie "to have both eyes looking in unparallel directions", is *loucher*. The medical noun for squinting , in that meaning,  is *le strabisme*.

*Cligner des yeux* is blinking, ie closing and opening one's eyelids rapidly. *Plisser les yeux* implies you keep your eyelids partly closed for a while, not just for a split moment as when blinking.

So, yes, I think this définition you found that equates *cligner des yeux* with "fermer les yeux à demi" is misleading IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Greg Unfortunately, I do not understand your last sentence.

Comment: My bad, I see now there was a word I left out. I will edit it, hopefully it will be better.

Answer (score -4):

No, "cligner des yeux"» does not mean "to squint"; the meaning should be exclusively "to blink". The definition in "Le Robert" leads to ambiguity.

> verbe transitif Fermer à demi (les yeux) pour mieux voir.

This is the definition of plisser les yeux, which, let it be said, is a misnommer: the eyes are not being  subjected to a contraction (plisser), only the eyelids and surrounding muscles are. So, it is better to say "plisser les paupières".

> ([ref.](http://institutions.ville-geneve.ch/fr/bm/interroge/archives-questions-reponses/detail/question/pourquoi-plisse-t-on-les-yeux-pour-mieux-voir-br/)) « Pour expliquer l'amélioration de vision due au froncement, il faut se rappeler que notre œil fonctionne comme un appareil photo. L'objectif est le cristallin, la pellicule est la rétine. Pour qu'une photo soit nette, l'image doit se former exactement sur la pellicule. Suivant la distance du sujet, l'objectif se rapproche plus ou moins de la pellicule : c'est la mise au point. Un œil en pleine forme est capable de former une image nette sur la rétine, que l'objet soit lointain ou proche, en écrasant plus ou moins le cristallin: le but est alors de former l'image toujours au même endroit, sur la rétine. Mais si notre œil est myope ou hypermétrope, l'image d'un objet lointain se formera en avant de la rétine ou... après. Résultat: on voit flou. Si l'on plisse les paupières, on limite le faisceau de lumière entrant dans l'œil (les paupières et les cils interviennent): on le diaphragme disent les photographes. »
>
> Donc, plisser les yeux ne permet qu’aux personnes atteintes de myopie de mieux voir. Ceux qui ont une bonne vue, n’y verront pas plus clair.

> ([ref.](https://destinationsante.com/pourquoi-voit-on-mieux-quand-on-plisse-les-yeux.html)) C'est un réflexe pour beaucoup d'entre nous, particulièrement quand le soleil brille et que nous sommes sortis sans lunettes de soleil : nous plissons les yeux pour y voir plus clair. C'est donc une question de [régulation de l'entrée] de la lumière, mais ce peut aussi être un signe de myopie.

"Cligner" can result from various discomforts, including bad vision caused by a veil on the eye, and  it can also be a tic (hard to explain) and an unfrequent habit (also hard to explain).  However, "cligner", meaning "to blink" does not mean "close the eyes half way". The definition from Ac. is not quite correct.

> les fermer à demi. La lumière l’obligeait à cligner des yeux. Cligner des yeux facilite l’accommodation.

Their example is accurate though; What is usually called "cligner" goes along with a short period of getting used to strong light, which causes discomfort ("Cligner des yeux facilite l’accommodation"), but what people  really do is  "plisser les yeux" and the act of "cligner" which can be found along with the act of "plisser les paupières", in that case, is a mere reflex so as to shut off entirely the light; nevertheless, "cligner" should never be understood as a fixed  closing of the eyelids halfway; it is always a more or less full closing that doesn't last, and that can be repeated more or less rapidly or occur only once every so often.

- Il cligna de l'œil en regardant Abraham pour lui dire que c'était trop. (*What is always understood is that one unique blink from only one eye is produced.*)

Comment: −1. “The eyes are not being subjected to a contraction (plisser), only the eyelids and surrounding muscles are. So, it is better to say "plisser les paupières".” – This is based on a wrong, narrow-sighted understanding of the word _œil_, which actually commonly means more than the sole eyeball, as evidenced by definitions from Larousse: “Organe pair de la vue, formé, chez les mammifères, du globe oculaire et de ses annexes (paupières, cils, glandes lacrymales, etc.)” or Robert: “Partie visible de l'œil et les paupières.” …/…

Comment: …/… Just the same as for the English word _eye_ (“all the visible structures within and surrounding the orbit and including eyelids, eyelashes, and eyebrows” – Merriam-Webster).

Comment: Also, while the Academy and Robert are not immune from mistakes, where both of them agree on what _cligner_ means, as well as Larousse (“cligner les yeux, les paupières, les fermer à demi pour mieux distinguer en diminuant le champ visuel”), the TLF (“fermer les yeux à demi pour mieux voir”) or Bescherelle (1861: “fermer l’œil, les yeux à demi”), a much stronger case is needed to prove them wrong.

Comment: Finally, most of this answer is irrelevant verbiage.

Comment: @Philippe-André Lorin It can be taken for granted that authorities on the French language differ sometimes, and they do in this particular case: ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C5%93il) I. − [L'oeil en tant qu'organe de la vue] Le globe oculaire _et les divers milieux qu'il enferme_ constituant l'appareil optique de l'homme et de nombreux animaux. Be that as it may, I find it difficult to share your point of view to the effect of a "wider whole": if once in England a car could be called a motor, it is the case no more. Second, I doubt very much that the creators of this  (1/3)

Comment: @Philippe-André Lorin expression had in mind such an analytical view of the question and that they made a truly judicious choice, it is more likely that they couldn't see the eye for the eyelids, and didn't bother much with reality.Then we are told that the subject is either "œil" or "paupière"; that is for the least messy, it's either one or the other. As for the word itself,   "plisser", I can add a little more well  worth the ink it costs; Since the word means "introduce folds" ("plis"), where are those new folds when the eyelids go from open to half closed, (2/3)

Comment: @Philippe-André Lorin i.e. when they are   "plissées" ? The very opposite is the case: there is an unfolding.  Then we have to contend with the fact that "plisser" and "cligner" both mean half-open, more inconsistencies. I don't understand how you can be oblivious to those facts, how you can ignore the paltry assemblage that all that really amounts to.  (3/3)

Comment: You’re defending an idealized view of the meaning of words and confusing what you’d like the language to be with what it really is. Your view on the meaning of _œil_ is incompatible with common phrases such as _ouvrir les yeux_, _se frotter les yeux_, _des yeux bouffis_, etc.
Incidentally, you’re, again, quick to dismiss the work of lexicographers, while their choice of explicitly listing the acceptation you reject in addition to the more obvious one you’re defending indeed shows that they _did_ bother with reality – the reality and complexity of language, that is.

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin Why shouldn't my view be that of the lexicographers responsible for the definition in the TLFi? Why shouldn't I find absurd to say "plisser" when the right word is "déplisser" ? Let us waste no more time together in talk  that is bound to be vain in the way of convincing me; I'll keep my opinions unchanged on that subject and you'll keep yours.

Comment: Just for the record, your view goes far beyond what the TLF’s entry reads.